# Deleted local repository by accident on Source Tree

Tags: git, github, repository, delete-file, restore

Just one question. Is there a way of getting it all back? If so how? I was able to retrieve some of the files from the recycle bin but a lot are still missing. Help.

Comment: Are the changes committed?

Comment: Yes. I have all the necessary files and backups as well. I've been using bitbucket so everything there remains the same and untouched. Everything that was linked to my Documents folder was gone, partially retrieved it but not all of it. My experience with it is not overly extensive therefore I'm panicking.

Comment: I might get flamed for saying this, because there is probably a better way to just reset, but I would clone the repo. Go make a new directory, something like "my_project_copy" and then `git clone https://usersname@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git`

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your work was commited and pushed to bitbucket, there is no problem. As [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380341/deleted-local-repository-by-accident-on-source-tree/42383449#comment71910101_42380341) stated in the comments, you can just do a fresh `git clone`.

This is one of the big antvantages of centralized source control: no matter what happens to your local copy, you can restore the server side repository state any time.

Comment: An additional advantage is that if your remote repo somehow gets clobbered, you can restore it from one of the local copies.